# Getting mouse position while dragging (JS + HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently implementing a small demo app trying to get my head around drag and drop with HTML5. What I'm trying to do at the moment is getting the position of the cursor when the user is dragging however I'm having some issues.

It seems that the 'mousemove' event doesn't get fired when dragging which is stopping me from figuring out the current position of the mouse. I could use the 'drag' event, however I can't figure out how to get the position from the 'drag' event object.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
//  JavaScript

document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var dragX = e.pageX, dragY = e.pageY;

    console.log("X: "+dragX+" Y: "+dragY);
}, false);

//  jQuery

$("body").bind("dragover", function(e){
    var dragX = e.pageX, dragY = e.pageY;

    console.log("X: "+dragX+" Y: "+dragY);
});
```

Runnable code snippet below:

```js
// JavaScript (a really great library that extends jQuery, check it out)

document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){
e = e || window.event;
var dragX = e.pageX, dragY = e.pageY;

console.log("X: "+dragX+" Y: "+dragY);
}, false);

// jQuery (the native-language JavaScript is written in)

$("body").bind("dragover", function(e){
var dragX = e.pageX, dragY = e.pageY;

console.log("X: "+dragX+" Y: "+dragY);
});
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
  <body>LOL drag something over me (open the console)</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of dragover events. Wouldn't it be a good ideea to ignore the most of them ? Let's say.. process every 10th event ? Right now I don't know how I would do this, but I would take the time to think about it.

Comment: @Tchypp Well, yes, there's a lot of events, pointer position updates are bound to generate a lot of events. It depends on what you're doing during those events, and how intensive it is. Most people need real-time info, not every-so-pixels updates. Those cost of keeping track of the start of dragging events, incrementing for each event, and only acting on the 10th event would have to be weighed against acting during every event.

Answer (score 16):

```
document.ondragover = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var x = evt.pageX,
        y = evt.pageY;

    console.log(x, y);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VZnxp/).

If you were using jQuery...

```
$(document).on('dragover', function(evt) {
    var x = evt.pageX,
        y = evt.pageY;

    console.log(x, y);

});
```

Comment: ... = function(evt) { evt = evt || window.event; ... }

Comment: @alex So why didn't you do it?