# Are mousemove events disabled while dragging an element?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to move an element by watching mousemove events on the document while the element is being dragged (using html5 drag and drop). I added a mousemove listener on the document on a parent element that fires whenever I move my mouse, but once I start dragging another child element I stop seeing mousemove events and once I stop dragging I see the events again. I don't see it anywhere in the API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) that dragging disables these events, but I can't tell how I could be stopping them from my code. Is this just part of html5 drag and drop that it disables the mousemove events while dragging?

I am using angular2 to detect mousemove. I've tried two different ways:

1)

```
@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
    onMouseMove(event) {
        console.log('Global mousemove: ', event);
    }
```

2)

```
constructor(
      public element: ElementRef,
      private renderer: Renderer2) {
        element.nativeElement.draggable = true;
      }
this.mouseMoveListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
```

Comment: maybe you drag the element outside of the listening element area?

Comment: I was listening for mousemove on the entire document though, and I wasn't leaving the browser window when dragging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting mouse position while dragging (JS + HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798167/getting-mouse-position-while-dragging-js-html5) - TL;DR you can use the `dragover` event which seems to have good performance and which fires whenever the mouse is moved

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove): "The mousemove event is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved while over an element." When you're dragging the element mouse is not moving **over it** - instead it moves synchronously **with the element**. I think you should consider "ondrag" event for this purpose - [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

Comment: I am not listening for the mousemove over the element being dragged though, I was listening for the global mousemove on the entire document.

Comment: ondrag has really, really bad performance and can't be used for what I'm trying to do. I tried it out but it was terrible.

Comment: @AlexEgli this is indeed really annoying, I am facing the same issue also. have you figured out anyway to replace or to recover the `mousemove` event while dragging?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai To be honest I don't remember if my current code solved the issue or if there was something else that was the underlying problem. What I ended up doing was using observables on the document. I used fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `pointermove` event, that does the job ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're right, `mousemove` events are disabled while an element is being dragged. You need to listen to a `drag` event instead (or perhaps to both `mousemove` and `drag`, depending on what you need). The drag event works even with a global handler.

```
document.addEventListener('drag', (e) => console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY))
```

You can test this with a dummy draggable element:

```
<div draggable>Test</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not in Firefox: `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` are always `0` for the drag event. So the only solution I found is using the `onDragOver` event applied to the document, so it can be triggered during while dragging, retrieving the clientX and clientY coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually dispatch one element(b)'s mousemove event (whitch is not dispatched automatically) when dragging another element(a)

```
a.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
    b.dispatchEvent('mousemove', e)
})
```

The dragover event gets a DragEvent, and the mousemove event gets a MouseEvent.
The former inherits from the latter, so I think it's OK to pass DragEvent to mousemove event handler