# How to use Vue mouse events with composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vuejs3

I am just trying to see how @mouseup, @mousedown, @mousemove events are working.
I have just a div:

// html

```
<div class="test" @mousemove="mouseMove" @mousedown="mouseDown" @mouseup="mouseUp">{{x}}</div>
```

// CSS

```
.test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

// Vue

```
  setup() {
    const x = ref(0);

    const mouseMove = event => {
      console.log("Mouse Moved ", event.x, event.y);
      x.value = event.x;
    };

    const mouseDown = event => {
      console.log("Mouse Down", event.x, event.y);
    };

    const mouseUp = event => {
      console.log("Mouse Up", event.x, event.y);
    };

    return {
      x,
      mouseMove,
      mouseDown,
      mouseUp
    };
  }
```

Now every time I click, I can see all 3 events called once, but nothing happens when I click and drag, no event is called.

```
Mouse Moved  106 729
Mouse Down 106 729
Mouse Up 106 729
```

Why is that ? I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: Not really a Vue issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46186173/are-mousemove-events-disabled-while-dragging-an-element#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=From%20here%3A%20%22The%20mousemove%20event,moves%20synchronously%20with%20the%20element.

Comment: I want to resize the div and all examples are using mouseevent event, but not with Vue, just plain html. So I thought I will do the same, but using this event in vue. Why it is behaving differently ?

Comment: For example, https://codepen.io/mannuelf/pen/wJwMjX this works, but it is not using composition api, so not sure what exactly is wrong with my example :/

Comment: In your codepen, I'm not seeing the mouse events while dragging. Do you have a repro using the composition API?

Comment: https://codepen.io/adrianstanciu24/pen/GRorVyj for some reason here it works. I don't get it...

Comment: My bad, it works in my project too, but I always tested with the Developers tools open, in that case it doesn't work. Which is strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Vue composition API, a declarative approach would be to use the [useMouse](https://vueuse.org/core/useMouse) composable function